# Contar cuantos solicitudes aceptadas tengo con tal agente

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una tabla donde tengo  columnas la cual
"ParaAgenteId" es el dato que tengo para el agente. y otra columna donde tengo "aceptadas" la cual es si este agente ha aceptado dicha solictud donde "aceptadas" es de tipo boleano. Quiero saber cuantas veces ha aceptado las solicitudes (osea, cuantas veces ha elegido el true, que tengo el Aceptadas)

Aqui tengo el viewBag que tengo para otra.

```
ViewBag.Aceptadas = db.SolicitudReasignaciones.Where(x => x.Aceptada == true).Count();
```

Esta variable, me dice cuantas solicitudes en total hay por todos, lo cual yo quiero filtrar por agente cuantas ha aceptado.

Aqui tengo mi tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No me queda claro si queres "filtrar" por agente, es decir para un agente decir cuantas solicitudes tenes aceptadas, o "agrupar" por agente, que implica tener una lista de agente, cantidad.

Vamos primero por filtrar, supone que quieres el agente 1:

```
ViewBag.Aceptadas = 
    db.SolicitudReasignaciones
      .Where(x => x.DbAgente == 1 && x.Aceptada == true).Count()
```

Si en cambio queres agrupado por agente:

```
ViewBag.AceptadasPorAgente = 
    db.SolicitudesReasignaciones
      .GroupBy(x => x.DbAgente)
      .Select(x => new { Agente = x.Key, Cantidad = x.Where(y => y.Aceptada).Count());
```

No lo probe en el compilador, por lo que no se si compila o anda, pero es por ahí y sino cualquier cosa comenta lo que no funciona.